# How to get the size of groups as well as other aggregations in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

When using pandas, I often have the need to compute aggregations over groups (sums and means being the most frequent) as well as getting the size of the groups.

I have come across several ways to achieve this goal, however none of them feels simple enough as compared to the simplicity of my requirement.

**Sample DataFrame**

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'client': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
        'order': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
        'revenue': [10, 25, 7, 35, 52],
        'margin': [2, 6, 3, 9, 13],
    }
).set_index(['client', 'order'])
```

Let's say I want to compute the total revenue and margin for each client, as well as the number of orders placed so that I can afterward compute some composite indicators like 'revenue per order'.

The result should be:

```
        revenue  margin  order_count
client                              
1            42      11            3
2            87      22            2
```

**Solution 1: computing multiple aggregation and joining**

```py
agg = df.groupby('client')[['revenue', 'margin']].sum()
agg2 = df.groupby('client').size().rename('size')
agg.join(agg2)
```

This solution yields the correct result, however it is quite impractical when chaining multiple operations as the chain is broken whenever a variable assignment is needed.

**Solution 2: reseting the index and passing a dictionary of aggregation functions**

```py
df.reset_index().groupby('client').agg(
    {
        'revenue': 'sum',
        'margin': 'sum',
        'client': 'size',
    }).rename({'client': 'order_count'}, axis=1)
```

This is my preferred way so far, however I find it disturbing to constantly have to set/reset index in method chaining. It also feels a bit awkward to have to count some arbitrarily chosen index level values (i.e. 'client' in this case) rather than getting the actual group sizes.

**Solution 3: passing a dictionary of aggregation function and then flattening the columns**

```py
df.groupby('client').agg(
    {
        'revenue': ['sum', 'size'],
        'margin': 'sum',
    }
)
```

This one does not answer my issue either, as it returns dataframe with a `MultiIndex` for the columns that require further work to get flattened and renamed.

Comment: You can `groupby(level=0)`, i.e. `df.groupby(level=0).agg(revenue=("revenue","sum"), margin=("margin","sum"), order_count=("margin","size"))` without the need to reset index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think reset index is not necessary, if use some newer pandas version use named aggregation, here for count is possible use any column, so change `client` to `margin`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('client').agg(revenue=("revenue","sum"),
                               margin=("margin","sum"),
                               order_count=("margin","size"))
print (df1)
        revenue  margin  order_count
client                              
1            42      11            3
2            87      22            2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know about named aggregation, and it worked like a charm.